# Array.prototype.slice shim for non-arrays in older Internet Explorers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser

I am interested in finding or writing a pseudo-shim to allow Array.prototype.slice to support non-arrays (while working in the same manner across browsers).

I know there are interfaces like NamedNodeMap, HTMLCollection, etc. which can be converted, e.g., in Firefox but not in IE <= 8.

Two questions:

1. Does IE indeed not work with the arguments object as some people have said? (I only have IE 10 installed, and it works fine even in IE5 quirks/IE7 mode (and it is fine with a hand-made array-like object as well).)
2. What kind of duck-typing or such could I use to comprehensively support all of the non-array types supported in some browsers when applied with `Array.prototype.slice.call()`? For example, I might duck-type for `item` as a function and try to get a valid value back when supplying a sample number like `0`. Firefox and IE8 both accept length even as strings (parsed into an integer). Will browsers like Firefox similarly work with any DOM object as long as it has a `length` property?

Comment: Older IE *does* work with the `arguments` object, because it's a native object.

Comment: ...and I can't figure out what you're asking in your point 2.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I think the OP is talking about the fact that `arguments` doesn't have a `slice` method. But doesn't know it can be overcome by using something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);`

Comment: @Ian: But then there would be no differentiation between IE and other browsers. I'm pretty sure OP means the `Array.prototype.slice.call()` technique.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yeah I'm not sure what I'm thinking. Re-reading the post, I think you're right, but I'm still confused what the OP means

Comment: Do not assume that something works in old IE just because you've tested it in compatibility mode. Compat mode has significant differences to a real copy of the IE version. You **must** test it in a real copy of each IE version you want to support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on arguments... And the second question is about Array.prototype.slice.call().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [recently asked and related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676396/portability-of-array-prototype-on-array-like-objects-or-ever-native-host-objec#comment40155878_25676396) that caused this older question to get rediscovered.

There's a polyfill for `Array.prototype.slice()` here on the [MDN page for .slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) that will work with all browsers for making a copy of any array-like object.   Since, this polyfill is only needed for older versions of IE, the polyfill starts with a specific test for something that fails in older versions of IE (thus it only installs itself when needed).

```
try {
    // Can't be used with DOM elements in IE < 9
    _slice.call(document.documentElement);
} catch (e) {
    // we know we're in IE < 9 here
}
```

The polyfill, then uses the standard test to see if the object is a real array:

```
// test if this is an actual array
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === '[object Array]')
```

So, on real arrays, the regular built-in `.slice()` is used.  The polyfill then goes on to implement it's own copy function by just using `.length` and `[index]` for reading content which are safe on any array-like object and it returns the contents copied into a new array.

---

To your specific questions:

> Does IE indeed not work with the arguments object as some people have said? (I only have IE 10 installed, and it works fine even in IE5 quirks/IE7 mode (and it is fine with a hand-made array-like object as well).)

The arguments object is a native Javascript array-like object (not a host object and not a real array) so there are no particular quirks with making a copy of it.  There are some new restrictions added to the `arguments` object in `strict` mode, but one can still make a copy of it.  The usual way to make a copy of the `arguments` object that works in all browsers is:

```
var items = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

One has to use `Array.prototype.slice` because the arguments object itself is not an array and does not have array methods on it.

> What kind of duck-typing or such could I use to comprehensively support all of the non-array types supported in some browsers when applied with Array.prototype.slice.call()? For example, I might duck-type for item as a function and try to get a valid value back when supplying a sample number like 0. Firefox and IE8 both accept length even as strings (parsed into an integer). Will browsers like Firefox similarly work with any DOM object as long as it has a length property?

`Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === '[object Array]'` is the foolproof way to test if something is an actual array.  I'm not aware of any duck-typing method to see if something is an array-like object other than testing to see if the object has a `.length` property and if you can use `[index]` to read values without causing an exception.

If you want to work on as many older browsers as possible and as many types of non-array objects as possible, then I'd suggest you use the above linked polyfill on the MDN page as that is what it is specifically designed for.

Since the world is (finally) starting to move beyond the older versions of IE, if you can now live with only supporting IE9 and above, then you can the `Array.prototype.slice.call()` method on all array-like objects (anything that has a `.length` property that corresponds to how many items there are that can be accessed with integer indexes via `[i]` and you won't even need the polyfill.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot I had actually started that code on MDN myself (with something looking more like this: https://gist.github.com/brettz9/6093105 ) (and forgetting to answer things myself here), though I see the code on MDN now improves it by handling negative values.

Comment: Is there a universal shim that brings IE up to Chrome on all fronts (html,css,javascript)?

Comment: @toddmo - That's an extremely tall order, some of which probably can't be done via shim. I'm not aware of any single shim that attempts to tackle all HTML, CSS and Javascript compatibility issues. You can use the jQuery library which gives you a DOM interface that works across all browsers. This is not a shim for the standard interface, but rather a new interface that is made to work across all browsers. This attempts to hide some HTML and CSS issues, but not all. It does not attempt to add features to the Javascript language. Also "up to Chrome" is a moving target in every new Chrome release.