# Portability of Array.prototype.* on array like objects or ever native/host objects

Tags: javascript, standards, portability, ecmascript-5

ESMA 262 5.1 for many `Array.prototype` functions say that they are **intentionally generic** and described in terms of `[[Get]]`, `[[Put]]`, etc operations on `Object`, but also require `length` property.

So them allowed to work on build-in objects, like:

```
obj = {"a":true, "length":10};
Array.prototype.push.call(obj, -1);
console.log(obj); // Object { 10: -1, a: true, length: 11 }
```

For native objects standard have note:

> Whether the push function can be applied successfully
>       to a host object is implementation-dependent.

Is `arguments` host object? Seems that all DOM (as `NodeList`) are host objects. And them work in modern browsers.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Streamlining_cross-browser_behavior) warn about `< IE9`. What about another browsers? What about `nodejs` native objects? What about Rhino/Nashorn native objects?

**UPDATE** @jfriend00 Hm, I didn't think about `[[Put]]` operation... In ECMA 5.1 I found special notes about such situation:

```
Host objects may implement these internal methods in any manner
unless specified otherwise; for example, one possibility is that
[[Get]] and [[Put]] for a particular host object indeed fetch and
store property values but [[HasProperty]] always generates false.
However, if any specified manipulation of a host object's
internal properties is not supported by an implementation, that
manipulation must throw a TypeError exception when attempted.
```

So in bad case you get `TypeError`!

Comment: I don't think you can "assume" that any Array functions work on host objects unless you specifically test them in all browsers and all versions of those browser that you wish to support.  In particular, you should assume that they will NOT work if they are modifying the object such as `.push()` or `.splice()`.  They are more likely to work if they are just copying some elements into a new array such a `.slice()`.  As for node.js, what native objects are you asking about that aren't already actual arrays?

Comment: Responding to your edits.  You'd get `TypeError` if and only if the browser actually followed the specification.  If all browsers followed all the specifications perfectly, all this would be a lot easier.  I stand by my recommendation that you'd have to test every browser version/combination you wanted to support.  The better solution is to immediately make a copy of any non-Array into an actual array.  In general, making a copy is a pretty safe thing to do because ALL array-like elements have a length and a means of iterating them (usually with `[index]`) which is all you need to make a copy.

Comment: FYI, the first code example in your question is a bit non-nonsensical.    Why `.push()` into a JS object?  You need a key and value for something to be a property of an object and `.push()` ONLY provides the value.  That seems like a mismatch from the beginning and something you should never do or even attempt to do.

Comment: @gavenkoa: `Arguments` is a native object, and "mutating" Array methods will fail on both native and host objects if the object is immutable.

Comment: @jfriend00: The `.push()` example isn't nonsensical. The `.push()` method provides the key (the new index) automatically based on the analysis of the current `.length`, which his object provided. It's really no different from doing the same on a jQuery object for example.

Comment: @cookiemonster - OK, I see your point.  But, you wouldn't catch me using `.push()` on a non-array.  I still think this whole line of reasoning of using a broad set of Array methods on non-array objects is just risky programming.  If you want to do array operations on something that isn't an actual array, then copy it into an actual array where you then have fully supported methods with no questions about what works and doesn't work or write your own code to carry out the operation in a way that you know is guaranteed to be safe based on the known capabilities of the type of object you have.

Comment: @jfriend00: I mostly agree with that. I think there's room for uses of Array-like objects, though I think often there would be benefit to having an actual, internal Array with methods on the object that access it as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you never really got a complete answer, I'll take a stab at answering some of the questions you posted.

> Is arguments host object?

`arguments` is part of the Javascript language, not a host object.  It has a pretty well defined behavior which has been modified some when running in `strict` mode.  Since `arguments` does not persist beyond the current function call (not even in a closure) and since it is not meant to be mutable, the usual way of handling the arguments object is to immediately make a copy into a real array where you can then use all the normal array methods on it and it can persist in a closure to be accessed by a local function.

> MDN docs warn about < IE9. What about another browsers?

It's not very specific to generalize here about a particular browser.  Instead, you'd have to examine a specific object and then specific versions of a browser.  Older versions of IE did have a reputation for having host objects that didn't interoperate as well with Javsacript (in this way), but you'd really have to examine a specific object to know what you could and couldn't do.

> What about nodejs native objects?

node.js is much more pure Javascript environment than the browser because there is no DOM, no `window` object, etc...  Did you have any specific node.js objects in mind that you wanted to ask about?  In my somewhat limited experience with node.js, I'm just seeing actual JS objects, though there are many places that node.js interfaces with the OS so perhaps there are some non JS objects in those interfaces (I haven't encountered any yet, but that is a possibility).

> So in bad case you get TypeError!

As I said in my comments, using any array object that attempts to modify the array such as `.splice()` is very likely to cause problems with host objects as many host objects are not meant to be modified directly.  Plus reading the specification and assuming that older browsers all follow the specification (without extensive testing to verify that) can be dangerous.  In particular, older versions of IE are famous for not following the specification.  So, again, you can't just assume you would get a `TypeError` without proper testing.

---

If you're looking for a general purpose safe way to code, one will never go wrong by copying an array-like host object into an actual array and then using array operations on the actual array.  That's guaranteed to be safe.    There's a cross-browser polyfill for `Array.prototype.slice` that works with all browsers for copying into an actual array on the [MDN page for .slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).  If you're only supporting IE 9 and up, you don't need the polyfill.

And, one should never assume that any operation that changes the array-like object is generally safe on a host object (there could be specific exceptions, but you'd have to do a lot of testing to be sure).  My preference is to write code that I know will be safe and does not require a lot of testing to guarantee that.  Copying into an actual array gives me that every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure it will work, better convert it to an array first.

To convert an array-like object to an array, you can use ES6 [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Currently only Firefox 32 supports it, but there is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill).

Alternatively, `[].slice.call(arrayLike)` will work on most browsers.

Comment: How is that different? You're using the very concept he's asking about in order to convert it to an Array, so your solution is subject to the same inquiry.

Comment: @cookiemonster As jfriend00 [said](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25676396/1529630#comment-40127487), it's more likely to work when just copying the elements into an array, like `slice`. Other methods which modify the array are more likely to fail.

Comment: But that's the same on native objects too. Any object that's immutable will fail if a mutating Array method is applied to it. What he's asking about is whether it's safe to use Array methods on host objects in general. Specific uses (whether native or host) are beyond the point. You're ultimately still offering a solution that begs the original question.